# $A$ unipotent and $A^k(U)=U$ for a subspace $U\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, does $A(U)=U$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a unipotent $n\times n$ complex matrix.
Let $k\geq 1$ be an integer.
Let $U$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $A^k(U)=U$.

Does this mean that $A(U)=U$?

**EDIT**: A matrix $M$ is called unipotent if $(M-I)^r=0$ for some integer $r\geq 1$.

Comment: Think about $A=\left[\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: The matrix you suggest is not unipotent. Is it?

Comment: Sorry, I had the definition of "unipotent" wrong.

Comment: Have you thought about the Jordan Canonical Form?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yes, I'm trying to work with the Jordan Form, but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:  I am doubting my answer now. I think I wrongly assumed that $((I+N)^k(I+N)^{j+1}x \in U$ when $x \in U$. This might be fixed by having *some* $k'$ such that $(1+N)^{k'}N^jx \in U$, which we can have by choosing $k'+j+1$ as a multiple of $k$. I'm not sure.**

Since $A$ is [unipotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unipotent), $A = I + N$, $N^m = 0$ for some $m$.

I claim that for $x \in U$ and $j \geq 0$,
$$(I+N)^k N^j x \in U.$$
The base case $j=0$ clearly holds. If it is true for $j$, then 
$$(I+N)^{k}(I+N)^{j+1}x = (I+N)^{k}(P(N)+N^{j+1})x \in U$$
where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $j$. But using the induction hypothesis, $(I+N)^k P(N)x \in U$, so we conclude $(I+N)^k N^{j+1}x \in U$.

Next I claim that for $x \in U$, then $N^j x \in U$ for $j \leq m$. By the nilpotency of $N$ we can write
$$(I+N)^k = I+P(N)N$$
where $P(N)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m-2$. Now for $x \in U$, using our previous result,
$$(I+N)^k N^{m-1} x = N^{m-1}x + P(N)N^mx = N^{m-1} x \in U.$$

Now we have
$$(I+N)^kN^{m-2}x=N^{m-2}x + P(N)N^{m-1}x = N^{m-2}x + p_0 N^{m-1}x \in U.$$

Because $N^{m-1}x \in U$, we conclude $N^{m-2}x \in U$. We can continue this method to finally achieve $Nx \in U$. From this we conclude $A(U) \subseteq U$.

Any unipotent matrix is invertible because $0=(I-A)^m=I+P(A)A$ means the inverse is $-P(A)$. So we can conclude that $A(U)=U$ identically.

Comment: As to the last point: $A$ restricted to $U$ is still unipotent, so it's invertible, so it's surjective.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! Of course. Any unipotent matrix is invertible because $0=(I-A)^m=I+P(A)A$ means the inverse is $-P(A)$. Didn't realize unipotent matrices are invertible.!

Comment: The answer looks great. I verified it once. I'm going to verify again and accept. Then, I will try to think how you thought of this :)

Comment: First I thought of $A=I+N$ and $A^k$ written as a binomial expression. Then I thought about what I can plug in and where, keeping in mind that if I have a $N^m+i$ term I can get rid of it.

Comment: @nayrb I said too myself that a _complex_ matrix is nipotent if and nly if $1$ is the only eigenvalue. That makes it clear that the restriction to an invariant subspace is unipotent, and also that unipotent implies invertible.

Comment: @Terry, I am doubting my answer now. I think I wrongly assumed that $((I+N)^k(I+N)^{j+1}x \in U$ when $x \in U$.